# How to get statistics of Apache ActiveMQ via command line

Tags: activemq-classic

We use ActiveMQ 5.15.6, and I need your guidance to extract the ActiveMQ statistics via command line. At the moment we use the web console to get the ActiveMQ statistics which can be accessed via:

```
http://<IPAddress>:8161/admin/queues.jsp
```

And when I run `./activemq bstat` it gives the below output

```
$./activemq bstat
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/bin/java'
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_252 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=62319k  max=932352k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/apps/activemq/current/conf/login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=/apps/activemq/current/conf:/apps/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.6//../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/apps/activemq/current -Dactivemq.base=/apps/activemq/current -Dactivemq.conf=/apps/activemq/current/conf -Dactivemq.data=/apps/activemq/current/data
Extensions classpath:
  [/apps/activemq/current/lib,/apps/activemq/current/lib/camel,/apps/activemq/current/lib/optional,/apps/activemq/current/lib/web,/apps/activemq/current/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /apps/activemq/current
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /apps/activemq/current
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /apps/activemq/current/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /apps/activemq/current/data
Connecting to JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
INFO: Broker not available at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Can you please advise what command or script do I need to run to get the stats via command line?

Comment: Are you running the `bstat` command on the same machine where the broker is running? Is remote JMX connectivity configured?

Comment: Hi Justin. Yes I am running on the same machine.

Comment: Is the broker configured to allow JMX connections on port `1099`?

Comment: No. I don't think so.

Comment: Then I suppose that's your problem as the `bstat` command is clearly trying to connect to `localhost:1099`.

Answer (score 1):

The output is telling you what is wrong namely that the command line client cannot connect to the JMX port where the broker should be exposing its JMX mbeans which the 'bstat' command uses to collect broker metrics.  You either need to enable JMX on the broker or configure the bstat command to point to where you've configure the JMX port to be:

`activemq bstat –jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi`

To understand the broker JMX configuration please read the docs which are located [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, how can configure or enable the JMX port. Is the config straight forward, apologies for these queries as my knowledge is very very basic.

Comment: My advice would be to read the broker documentation